# Prevent ContentPlaceHolder from rendering <DIV> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, panel

Is there any way to prevent a ASP.Net Panel from rendering a DIV?

Comment: gonna need to see your MasterPage html

Comment: Spoke too soon - sorry. It was ofcours a panel that was rendering the DIV

Answer (score 2):

You can set the div to be a server-side control and then access it through the code-behind:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">Some Content</div>
```

And then wherever you want to set the visibility:

```
var control = Page.FindControl("myDiv") as HtmlGenericControl;
control.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that hide every thing contained within that div? and in this case the whole child page contents?

Comment: @LordCover - It would hide everything contained in that div, yes. But that's what the OP is asking for...to stop rendering the div. He never mentions that all content is part of that div.

Answer (score 1):

as reflector says:

```
public Panel() : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
{
}
```

inherit Panel in your class and make constructor with tag you need.